# Microsoft Computer Vision OCR Read API charged as S3 transaction instead of S2

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using Microsoft Computer Vision API for OCR processing and I noticed that they are getting charged as S3 transactions instead of S2 in my bill.
[image]

I'm using the .NET SDK and the API I am using is this one.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.computervisionclientextensions.readasync?view=azure-dotnet

I have also confirmed that the actual REST API the SDK calls is the following POST /vision/v3.2/read/analyze
https://centraluseuap.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005

According to documentation, that should be the OCR Read API, am I correct?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/vision-api-how-to-topics/call-read-api

I am puzzled as to why my calls are getting charged as S3 instead of S2. This is important for me because S3 is 50% more expensive than S2. Using the Pricing Calculator, 1000 S2 transactions is $1, whereas 1000 S3 transactions is $1.5.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=cognitive-services

What's the difference between OCR and "Describe and Recognize Text" anyways? OCR (Optical Character Recognition) by definition must recognize text. I am calling the Read API without any of the optional parameters so I did not ask for "Describe" hence the call should be S2 feature rather than S3 feature I think.
[image]

I already posted this question at Microsoft Q&A but I thought SO might get more traffic hence help me get an answer faster.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/689767/computer-vision-api-charged-as-s3-transaction-inst.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To help you understand, you need a bit of history of those services. Computer Vision API (and all "calling" SDKs, whether C#/.Net, Java, Python etc using these APIs) have moved frequently and it is sometimes hard to understand which SDK calls which version of the APIs.

## API operations history

Regarding optical character reading operations, there have been several operations:

### Computer Vision 1.0

See definition [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc) was containing:

- `OCR` operation, a synchronous operation to recognize printed text
- `Recognize Handwritten Text` operation, an asynchronous operation for handwritten text (with "Get Handwritten Text Operation Result" operation to collect the result once completed)

### Computer Vision 2.0

See definition [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200). OCR was still there, but "Recognize Handwritten Text" was changed. So there were:

- `OCR` operation, a synchronous operation to recognize printed text
- `Recognize Text` operation, asynchronous (+ Get Recognize Text Operation Result to collect the result), accepting both printed or handwritten text (see `mode` input parameter)
- `Batch Read File` operation, asynchronous (+ "Get Read Operation Result" to collect the result), which was also processing PDF files whereas the other one were only accepting images. It was intended "for text-heavy documents"

Computer Vision 2.1 was similar in terms of operations.

### Computer Vision 3.0

See definition [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-ga/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499f21b).
Main changes: `Recognize Text` and `Batch Read File` were "unified" into a `Read` operation, with models improvements. No more need to specify handwritten / printed for example (see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/upgrade-api-versions?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)).

[image: Upgrade from 2.0 to 3.0]

```
The Read API is optimized for text-heavy images and multi-page, mixed language, and mixed type (print – seven languages and handwritten – English only) documents
```

So there were:

- `OCR` operation, a synchronous operation to recognize printed text
- `Read` operation, asynchronous (+ Get Read Result to collect the result), accepting both printed or handwritten text, images and PDF inputs.

Same for Computer Vision v3.1-preview.1, v3.1-preview.2, v3.1, v3.2-preview.1, v3.2-preview.2, v3.2-preview.3

## SDKs

All recent versions of the SDKs implementing a `Read` method are calling this 3.x. operation. See the changelog for example for .Net SDK [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/cognitiveservices/Vision.ComputerVision/CHANGELOG.md):

v7.0.x of the SDK "supports v3.2 Cognitive Services Computer Vision API endpoints."
[image: Changelog of SDK]

## Conclusion

It is normal that you are billed S3 for `Read`. But the calculator is misleading as the "Recognize Text" term should be changed for "Read".

If you really want to use `OCR` operation, use `RecognizePrintedTextAsync` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.computervisionclientextensions.recognizeprintedtextasync?view=azure-dotnet) of the SDK which is the one using it.

OCR is an old model, used only for printed text. Read operation is the latest model.
I can also confirm (based on a few tests that I made) that the performance is lower than Read operation. If you want to quickly test, you can use your key on [this website](https://cognitive-workbench.azurewebsites.net/vision/computer-vision): it is an open-source portal created by another Microsoft MVP, where I also contributed. You will be able to see both results of OCR and Read operations. It is currently using 6.0.0 SDK version of Computer Vision (see [source](https://github.com/PeterOrneholm/cognitive-workbench/blob/7fb349972e4fac53a3af29c3122722092536a830/src/Orneholm.CognitiveWorkbench.Web/Orneholm.CognitiveWorkbench.Web.csproj#L27)).

Sample:
OCR result:
[image: OCR output]
Read result:
[image: Read output]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation with some history!